# How to throw an exception but include parameters as part of the message?

Tags: php

What is the best way to do this:

```
$params = array ('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'); // etc etc

throw new Exception(
   "Could not do something because params << insert parameters >> was bad",  
    $code
 );
```

What is the best way to include the parameters as part of the exception and if it must simply go in the message, what is the best way to transform it into text so no details are lost?

Keep in mind, I want to see something like this:

```
"Could not do something because params: a = b, c = d was bad",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf` function

```
throw new Exception(
   sprintf("Could not do something because params %s, %s was bad", 'b', 'd'),  
    $code
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the count of array values/indexes is constant, You could do this:

```
throw new Exception(
    sprintf("Could not do something because params {$params['a']}, {$params['b']} was bad"),  
    $code
);
```

If You have different number of values in array, You could procced like this:

```
throw new Exception(
    sprintf("Could not do something because params " . implode(', ', $params) . " was bad"),  
    $code
);
```

And if You'd need also to include the array key for each value, You'd have to do something similar:

```
$excParams = array();
foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $excParams[] = "{$key} = {$val}";
}

throw new Exception(
    sprintf("Could not do something because params " . implode(', ', $excParams) . " was bad"),  
    $code
);
```